# Creating error message when all files not imported

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I have a subroutine that asks the user to select files in a specific folder and then the code reads and writes that data. However, sometimes the program skips files due to formatting issues, but no warning is given when a file is skipped. How can I add an error message to alert the user if any files were not imported? Would an 'On Error GoTo' work?

```
Sub GetData_Master

ADataLocation = "\\....."
BDataLocation = "\\..."

'Select Source Data
Answer = MsgBox ("A Data? <Yes> for A, <No> for B", vbYesNoCancel + vbDefaultButton1)
If Answer = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

        .InitialFileName = ADataLocation
        If Answer = vbNo Then .InitialFileName = BDataLocation
        .Filters.Add "Excel", "*.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm", 1
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Show

End With 'Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

'Read and Write Data
For i = 1 To Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems.Count
        Workbooks.Open Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(i), ReadOnly:=True

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets ("Summary")...
```

Comment: What code could I include that will notify the user if one of the files selected wasn't opened?

Comment: Where is the `Workbooks.Open` code where you're actually opening the file?

Comment: I've edited the code in the original post to include those lines. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What specifically means "formatting issues"? Dont you have error handling somewhere outside the sub?

Comment: The files are checklists and they have to be filled out correctly or the code won't read and write the data properly. If the checklists aren't filled out correctly, they get skipped, and I'd like to add a message notifying the user when that happens. No, I don't have error handling outside the sub. I'm trying to figure out how to code that correctly.

Comment: @Beginner - then you need to define what "correct" is and in the code check for that "correctness". If it's many things to consider, you can write a custom function that returns a Boolean. If it passes procede to write the data, otherwise skip and log the incorrect files for the user. Ideally each file will have a cell somewhere that determines its correctness, but I can see how that could not be feasible.

Comment: Why don't you include the part of the code where *the program skips files due to formatting issues*?

Comment: I hadn't added it because I thought the issue would need to be resolved either when the user selects all the files or when the files are first opened.

Comment: Should def follow up on @ScottHoltzman comment. You either need to define a measurable success **or** failure criteria and then proceed accordingly. (Do this if fail or this if success for ex)

Comment: Thank you all for the help.